# Alpine dockerfile: "cannot produce proc-macro...does not support these crate types"

Tags: docker, rust, alpine-linux, rust-cargo

Total rust noob here. Trying to build a sccache binary for linux x64 with `Redis: true`. I'm starting with an alpine image:

```
FROM rust:alpine3.10

WORKDIR /root

RUN apk --no-cache add --update curl
RUN curl -L https://github.com/mozilla/sccache/archive/0.2.11.tar.gz \
        -o sccache.tar.gz
RUN tar xf sccache.tar.gz

RUN cd sccache-0.2.11 &&\
    cargo build --features=all --release
```

I get:

```
error: cannot produce proc-macro for `derive-error v0.0.3` as the target `x86_64-unknown-linux-musl` does not support these crate types
```

Works fine if I `FROM rust`, which is based on `buster`. I could just go with this (and I will), but what is going on here? I'm so out of my element I am not even sure what questions to ask.

Related?: 
https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/59302

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `proc_macro` crate relies on a couple of features only available to dynamically-linked executables, and since `musl` is anything but that, you cannot use `proc_macro` on `musl`.

The issue related to this is here, and Alex describes quite well some of the issues and tradeoffs that'd need to be made to make this crate available on full static targets: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/40174

Just to confirm from the container:

```
~# docker run -ti rust:alpine3.10 /bin/sh
/ # rustup show
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
rustup home:  /usr/local/rustup
```

Comment: Does alpine use `musl` instead of `glibc`?

Comment: look at your target name

Comment: @DeusXMachina just checked the container, the target is indeed `1.37.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-musl (default)`. So, yes, you're running musl if you use that.

Comment: Ah yes, a bit more research turned up the fact that apparently they switched over at least 5 years ago. https://dev.suckless.narkive.com/jkpX0jsz/alpine-linux-switched-to-musl-libc

Comment: For the record, alpine is a distro centered around security and static linking is a pretty big thing there, for obvious reasons. It doesn't surprise me that it is based on musl for that reason

Comment: Oh I am alllll about the static linking. Right now dealing with a legacy project that is basically dynamic spaghetter.

Comment: This is no longer true.